# Why Friday is Called "Jumua"

Tags: arabic

Sunday is called as youmul ahad, and monday is youmul ithnain...
The rest of the days in a week except Friday are called with their number...
But what is the reason only Friday is called jumua?.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Although your question is more about Muslim countries than about Islam, "jumu'ah" is mentioned in several ahadith, and I think that makes this a good (but basic) on-topic question.

Answer (score 3):

The linguistic meaning of "jumuah" is from the root word "jama3ah" (jeem, ayn, meem) which means to gather together. Yawm al-Jumu'ah is thus dubbed because the Muslims gather together for salaat al-jumu'ah (Friday prayers) in congregation -- this is not something you can do individually, but must be done in a group.

Speaking of day names, Saturday is "Yawm As-Sabt" and also does not follow the numbering convention.